# Why are vectors so shallow?

Tags: scala, collections, vector, clojure, tree

What is the rationale behind Scala's vectors having a branching factor of 32, and not some other number? Wouldn't smaller branching factors enable more structural sharing? Clojure seems to use the same branching factor. Is there anything magic about the branching factor 32 that I am missing?

Comment: I blame the mainstream media.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would help if you explained what a branching factor is:

*The branching factor of a tree or a graph is the number of children at each node.*

So, the answer appears to be largely here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_15.html

> Vectors are represented as trees with a high branching factor. Every
>   tree node contains up to 32 elements of the vector or contains up to
>   32 other tree nodes. Vectors with up to 32 elements can be represented
>   in a single node. Vectors with up to 32 * 32 = 1024 elements can be
>   represented with a single indirection. Two hops from the root of the
>   tree to the final element node are sufficient for vectors with up to
>   2<sup>15</sup> elements, three hops for vectors with 2<sup>20</sup>, four hops for vectors
>   with 2<sup>25</sup> elements and five hops for vectors with up to 2<sup>30</sup> elements.
>   So for all vectors of reasonable size, an element selection involves
>   up to 5 primitive array selections. This is what we meant when we
>   wrote that element access is "effectively constant time".

So, basically, they had to make a design decision as to how many children to have at each node.  As they explained, 32 seemed reasonable, but, if you find that it is too restrictive for you, then you could always write your own class.

For more information on why it may have been 32, you can look at this paper, as in the introduction they make the same statement as above, about it being nearly constant time, but this paper deals with Clojure it seems, more than Scala.

http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/169879/files/RMTrees.pdf

Answer (score 8):

James Black's answer is correct. Another argument for choosing 32 items might have been that the cache line size in many modern processors is 64 bytes, so two lines can hold 32 ints with 4 bytes each or 32 pointers on a 32bit machine or a 64bit JVM with a heap size up to 32GB due to pointer compression.

Comment: Deleted the comment now, to avoid redundancy.

Comment: The modern cache line is 64bytes. Intel's very newest, very latest processors only might have 128bytes.

Answer (score 4):

It's the "effectively constant time" for updates.  With that large of a branching factor, you never have to go beyond 5 levels, even for terabyte-scale vectors.  Here's a video with Rich talking about that and other aspects of Clojure on Channel 9.  http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Rich-Hickey-and-Brian-Beckman-Inside-Clojure

Answer (score 4):

Just adding a bit to James's answer.

From an algorithm analysis standpoint, [image: http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21O%28log%20_b%20%28N%29%29%20%3D%20O%28log%20_k%20%28N%29%29.gif] because the growth of the two functions is logarithmic, so they scale the same way.

But, in practical applications, having 
[image] hops is a much smaller number of hops than, say, base 2, sufficiently so that it keeps it closer to constant time, even for fairly large values of N.

I'm sure they picked 32 exactly (as opposed to a higher number) because of some memory block size, but the main reason is the fewer number of hops, compared to smaller sizes.

I also recommend you watch this presentation on InfoQ, where Daniel Spiewak discusses Vectors starting about 30 minutes in: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Data-Structures-in-Scala